# Change column background color based on dropdown in another column apps script google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table of tasks - columns B:C contain the task content and column D contains the type of task. I would like to change the background color of B:C depending on what value is in D.

[image]
My function seems overly long and complicated. Would there be a way to check column D in a broad range (A1:D10), and if column D is blank value then replace B:C of the same row with the designated background color?

Right now my function would check each individual row. For example right now my function works correctly for the first task row (B1:C1 and D1). However, if I duplicate it to do the same for the 9 rows below it my function is going to be overly long and complicated. Is there a way to simplify this?

```html
function tbdropdown() {
  var tbddsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet19");
  var tbddrange0 = tbddsheet.getRange("D1").getValue();
    var tbddrange1 = tbddsheet.getRange("B1:C1");

if(tbddrange0 =="work") {
tbddrange1.setBackground("blue");
}
if(tbddrange0 =="school") {
tbddrange1.setBackground("red");
}
if(tbddrange0 =="personal") {
tbddrange1.setBackground("yellow");
}
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function tbdropdown() {
  var obj = { "work": "blue", "school": "red", "personal": "yellow" }; // These values are from your script.
  var tbddsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet19");
  var range = tbddsheet.getRange("D1:D" + tbddsheet.getLastRow());
  var colors = range.getDisplayValues().map(([d]) => Array(2).fill(obj[d] || null));
  range.offset(0, -2, colors.length, 2).setBackgrounds(colors);
}
```

- In this modification, by preparing `obj`, each color is set from the cell value.
- If you want to change the colors for the values, please modify `obj`.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setBackgrounds(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use conditional formatting with a custom formula to achieve this
[image: sample sheet with conditional formatting]

For each option you have, you will need a formatting rule with a custom formula like this

```
=INDIRECT( "D" & ROW() ) = "Work"
```

[image: conditional formatting rule]

Note that the value that you are comparing is case-sensitive, so the following formulas are different

```
=INDIRECT( "D" & ROW() ) = "Work"
=INDIRECT( "D" & ROW() ) = "work"
```

Comment: `INDIRECT` is not needed. Just `=$D1="Work"` will do the trick.